# Variable and Function help // Python

Tags: python, function, variables

Alright so here's the code

```
def user_password():
input('Please Enter Password: ')

#profiles
def intercept():
    user_password()
    if user_password == "intercept":
            print("this is working so far")
    else:
            print("Incorect Password")
def Jimmy():
    user_password()
    if user_password == "Jimmy":
            print("this is working so far")
    else:
            print("Incorect Password")
def Tommy():
    user_password()
    if user_password == "Tommy":
            print("this is working so far")
    else:
            print("Incorect Password")

#login
user_functions = dict(
    intercept=intercept,
    Jimmy=Jimmy,
    Tommy=Tommy,
    # ...
)
 user_input = input("Input function name: ") 

if user_input in user_functions:
    user_functions[user_input]()
else:
    print("Error: Unknown function.")
```

PROBLEMS:

- My code always starts with asking for the password even though I don't want it 
  to.

  - When I change the first variable to a function it fixes this
  - Why does it execute when I'm just setting the variable. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to use a function instead of a variable
- No matter what it always ends up as Incorrect Password even if I give the correct password

Comment: Since your first line of code is "user_password = input('Please Enter Password: ')" that's gonna be the first line to execute

Comment: `=` doesn't mean "make the thing on the left shorthand for the operation on the right". It means "do the thing on the right, and make the thing on the left a name for the object produced by doing the thing on the right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to write something like that:

```
def get_user_password():
   return input('Please Enter Password: ')


def Jimmy():
    user_password = get_user_password()
    if user_password == "Jimmy":
            print("this is working so far")
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how that works and why my code didn't work? Go over the code first pls cause I changed some stuff

Comment: @intercept your first line is a SyntaxError. Please find how to define a function and how to set a variable. ``def user_password = input('Please Enter Password: ')`` is doing none to these.

Comment: even if i do it correctly it says incorrect password